# download attachment file in vbulletin for unregistered user

Tags: php, attachment, vbulletin

I have a side script in my forums that allows to my users to upload some stuff from my forums.

I wanted to allow my users to upload attachment file from the forums, but vbulletin always show unregistered form.

So i'm asking is there a way that i can send username and password with attachment link, so vbulletin can identity my user and allow to download that attachment file?

I tried this:

```
$link = 'http://localhost/vb/attachment.php?attachmentid=2';
$username = 'admin';
$password = '1111';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($info);
print_r($output);
```

But as i said, unregistered form show up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. since both of my script are in one host, i used `copy` to copy my attachment file across my host. By this way i don't need to deal with vbulletin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are only wanting them to download the file if they are logged into the forums? If this is the case you could use something like this assuming you are using vbulletin.

if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid']) {  insert code to show download link here };

all that does is checks to see if the user is logged into the forums.

Comment: No not in forums,i want them to logged into the side script and from there they be able to download attachment file.

Comment: What version of Vbulletin are you using? Are you wanting the script page to keep the characteristics of the forum? i.e. forum header/footer and such? If so I will be able to help as soon as I get back to my pc this evening.

Comment: my vb version is 3.8.5, and side script is a complete different script in a different domain. The only common part between this two script is the user's system (which side script connect to vb's db).

Comment: by different domain in meant: vb = forums.mysite.com & sidescript = side.mysite.com